# adding an existing column to an existing table MS_Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

A little Background:

In this project, I am trying to combine 2 tables which I acquire from different applications.

One of the applications gives me several tables which I have successfully combined into 1 table:

```
DB_Total
```

The other application gives me a single Table with nothing but the Tagnames. This table is called:

```
TagNames_EA
```

---

Now, I would like to add the "Name" column from the "TagNames_EA" table into the "DB_Total" table  so I can compare the values in the "Name" fields.

So far, I have this code to compare and filter out the names that don't match:

```
SELECT
    d.Address,
    d.Type,
    d.Name,
    IIf(t.Name Is Null, False, True) AS match_found
FROM
    DB_Total AS d
    LEFT JOIN TagNames_EA AS t
    ON d.Name = t.Name;
```

This works great, but I would also like to see the "Name" values from the TagNames_EA table in the DB_Total table.

---

I know It's possible to add a column to an existing table with the

```
ALTER TABLE DB_Total
ADD Names_EA
```

But, when I try this:

```
ALTER TABLE DB_Total
ADD Names FROM TagNames_EA AS Names_EA
```

It does not work

Is there an easy way to do this?

Edit: I tried to simplify the way I explained my situation.

Edit2: Example

In the "DB_Total" table, I have a list of names, which should be exactly the same as the names in the "EA_Names" table.

```
DB_Total:
     Name
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[3]
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[4]
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[5]
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[6]
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[7]
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[8]
```

However, sometimes mistakes are made and I would like to check if there are names that don't have matches. Like this:

```
TagNames_EA
    Name
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[3]
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[4]
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[5]
S1\SVS_AK\EMA[6]  <--- This is a Mistake and will come up as a mismatch
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[7]
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[8]
```

Currently, the code I use, adds a new column to my DB_Total table, with either the value "-1" (for a match) or the value "0" (for a name without a match)

Which looks like this:

```
DB_Total:               
     Name               match_found
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[3]            -1
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[4]            -1
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[5]            -1
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[6]             0
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[7]            -1
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[8]            -1
```

What I would like to accomplish is a table that includes the following:

```
DB_Total:               
     Name                 Names_EA       match_found
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[3]     S1\SVS_AK\ENA[3]        -1
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[4]     S1\SVS_AK\ENA[4]        -1
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[5]     S1\SVS_AK\ENA[5]        -1
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[6]     S1\SVS_AK\EMA[6]         0
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[7]     S1\SVS_AK\ENA[7]        -1
S1\SVS_AK\ENA[8]     S1\SVS_AK\ENA[8]        -1
```

After the comment from Joe, I'm starting to doubt this is the correct way to do this if I also want to see the name values from EA_Table in the same table.

Comment: I am confused.  You are joining on name.  So, the names in the Tagnames_EA table are already there - they're the same as the names on the DB_Total table.  Are you asking for the non-matches to also show up?

Comment: I understand the confusion, I will try to make it a little clearer for someone that has not been working with this database for the past 2 weeks!

Comment: Currently, it adds a column to the DB_Total table named "match_found" 

If the names from the two tables match, the corresponding field in the "match_found" column returns "-1", if they don't match, it returns a "0"

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help because I don't think you understood my comment.  Based on the SQL code you posted above, your new table (if you created it from that select) would have all rows of DB_Total table with an indicator if it was found in the tagnames table; but there is no second variable to add on.  Can you show an example of the data in each table and the result you would like to see?

Comment: I hope this edit made clear what I currently have and what I would like to accomplish @Joe

Comment: How are you going to identify that the EMA row should be matched up to the ENA row?  Your join won't accomplish that, certainly.

Comment: I started to think about this indeed and the solution  that SchmitzIT gave, leaves out the values that don't match because of the line "ON d.Name = t.Name" Wich I think is as close as I can get to the solution I need.

Comment: It would be possible to find partial matches, and it would be possible to list unmatched rows. Is the difference always one letter (EMA/ENA)?

Comment: No, the difference is always unknown, its even unknown wether there will be a difference. The only reason there could be a mismatch is user error. That's why I want this check. The difference could be (ena/ema) or it could be (refrigerator/freezer) for example

Comment: In that case, how about look for mismatches on both sides? That is, records with no match in DB_Total and a second set, records with no match in TagNames_EA, the second set must be user error and the first set is possible matches, yesno?

Comment: Well, that is not neccesary. In this application, the names in the column DB_Total, are always right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your ALTER statement of course wouldn't work. You'd typically add an empty NULL-able column first, and then use a second `INSERT` statement to fill in the data. However, you will have to have another column, other than name, that should define what value from the _EA table does into the DB_Total table, as otherwise you would not be able to guarantee with 100% certainty you are matching the proper rows from both tables.

You can try the following to receive what I think is your desired result:

```
SELECT
    d.Address,
    d.Type,
    d.Name,
    t.name,
    IIf(t.Name Is Null, False, True) AS match_found
FROM
    DB_Total AS d
    LEFT JOIN TagNames_EA AS t
    ON d.Name = t.Name;
```

This should show you both name results next to one another. However, it would probably be easier if you had some unambiguous ID-value to ensure you really have the properly matching rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    d.Address,
    d.Type,
    d.Name,
    IIf(t.Name Is Null, False, True) AS match_found,
    t.name as name_ea
FROM
    DB_Total AS d
    FULL OUTER JOIN JOIN TagNames_EA AS t
    ON d.Name = t.Name;
```

That gives you the nonmatches; however it does not actually show you which match up to which - it would be up to you to work out which corresponded later on.

Comment: This code generates an error after wich it highlites the "t" from t.name as name_ea within the SELECT instruction

Comment: I left out a comma, try again.